# How to start init, but not startup scripts?

Tags: linux, init, busybox

I specified `rdinit=/bin/sh` and manually booted the system (in chroot) from command line, complete with mounted filesystems, network services and X desktop. The init is still busybox's /bin/sh.

The problem is that I see many uncollected "zombie" processes.

How to start proper init, but not all boot scripts again? I feel that if I "exec chroot /mnt /sbin/init" then it either starts extra things or exit with some error and "kernel panic".

(Don't advice just to reboot)

**Update**: Just executed into system bash (instead of busybox's one) `exec chroot /mnt /bin/bash` and now zombies gone.

Comment: Check out how Busyboxs init works: http://spblinux.de/2.0/doc/init.html and http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/From-PowerUp-To-Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-6.html is good too

Comment: This file must be on the kernel ramdisk instead of on the root filesystem.